Using GRASS r.neighbors with weight file
I am new to QGIS and GRASS and am trying to calculate a median cell value from an irregular neighborhood around each raster pixel using GRASS r.neighbors function.
I want to calculate the median value for the 4 rasters that share a 'long side' with the focal raster. I think I can do this by using a weighting file where rasters that I don't want used (i.e., the diagonals and focal raster) are given a weight of '0' and the 4 rasters that I want used are weighted as '1'. I think I can achieve this using the following weighting scheme:

I put this in a 3-line text file called 'weight.txt' that looks like:
010
101
010

My input raster is 'C:/TEMP/temp_subset.tif' with values in Band 1.
This is my Python code that I think should run:
processing.run("grass7:r.neighbors", {'input':'C:/TEMP/temp_subset.tif','selection':None,'method':1,'size':3,'gauss':None,'quantile':'','-c':False,'-a':False, 'weighting_method':'file', 'weight':'C:/TEMP/weight.txt','output':'C:/Temp/windowtest.tif','GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None,'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':0,'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT':'','GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META':''})

However, when I run this code, the calculations are done for the 9 raster values that surround and include the focal raster. It seems like the weight.txt file is not being used.
I suspect that I have missed something simple. At least I hope so!
